# Delete items from nested dict recursively

Tags: python, recursion

Sorry for stupid question, but what am i doing wrong?

I have nested dict, which i was hope to dump into json.

```
[{'text': 'Root', 'children': [{'text': 'X', 'children': [None, None], 'id': 2}, {'text': 'Y', 'children': [], 'id': 3}], 'id': 1}]
```

I need to remove all 'None' values from it. Here is my code:

```
for items in sub_tree_dicts:
    del_null(items['children'])

def del_null(childrens):
    for child in childrens:
        if child is None:
            childrens.remove(child)
        else:
            del_null(child['children'])
```

Unfortunately, code does not work as expected and removes only first 'None' from the list. Where am I wrong?

Thanx.

Comment: Don't modify a dictionary while you're iterating over said dictionary. Your `childrens.remove(child)` is breaking your for loop.

Comment: You know you do not need to remove the `None` when you want to convert to JSON since `json.dumps()` will modify it to `null`...?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You are right. I have corrected my comment.

Comment: Think about what happens when you remove `None` the way you are attempting to for something like `[None, None, 42]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't modify a dictionary/list/etc while you're iterating over the list. You can break the reference so the loop doesn't know where to go.

I'm fairly certain there's a better way but the way I would do it without modifying your code too much is this:

```
for items in sub_tree_dicts:
    del_null(items['children'])

def del_null(childrens):
    invalid_children = []
    for child in childrens:
        if child is None:
            invalid_children.append(child)
        else:
            del_null(child['children'])
    for child in invalid_children:
        childrens.remove(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [{'text': 'Root', 'children': [{'text': 'X', 'children': [None, None], 'id': 2}, {'text': 'Y', 'children': [], 'id': 3}], 'id': 1}]
d = {}
def filter_none(s, last=None):
   if last:
       new_list = [{a:[i for i in b if i is not None] if isinstance(b, list) else b for a, b in c.items()} for c in s]
       return new_list
   for a, b in s.items():
      if not isinstance(b, list):
         d[a] = b
      else:
         d[a] = filter_none(b, last=a)

filter_none(s[0])
new_d = [d]
```

Output:

```
[{'text': 'Root', 'children': [{'text': 'X', 'children': [], 'id': 2}, {'text': 'Y', 'children': [], 'id': 3}], 'id': 1}]
```

Comment: Good lord man. I know you're probably going for efficiency here but I'm an experienced python user and the readability here is so rough it's even taking me a while to figure out what's going on xD.